# Well pump won't shut off or get above 32 psi

Tags: plumbing

Turned off power & valve to house. Tank and gauge read 32 psi. Drained the tank (very little water in it) Tank psi remained at 32psi but gauge dropped to zero very quickly. Took the tank pressure down to 28 psi (I have a 30/50 switch) powered back up with valve to house still closed, gauge still not going past 32 psi, opened valve to house and no change? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, can't afford a plumber right now and don't want to burn out my submerged pump.

Found the following info on the QD control box at well: model# 2801084915 1HP 230 volts SF max amp 9.8

[image: Pump Control Box]

Comment: Can you add any model numbers for the pump?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably having a pump problem that may require you to pull the pump and have a well guy clean the impellers, repair the pump or replace the pump and/or motor. Usuall, if the pump has a reduced supply or pressure the impellers are at fault.

Comment: True that or a leak in the pipe I have seen that a few times where a small hole opens at a specific pressure.+